# Cannot access file error to pull data from Excel in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: excel, vb.net

*Resolved. There was a hidden active build in the background.

I'm attempting to pull data from an existing excel sheet into the VB program as an array, however I've run into an error at the build stage. I'm quite new to VB and inexperienced in this use.

The existing code is as follows:

```
    Dim objApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objBook As Excel._Workbook

  Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim objSheets As Excel.Sheets
        Dim objSheet As Excel._Worksheet
        Dim range As Excel.Range

        'Get a reference to the first sheet of the workbook.
        On Error GoTo ExcelNotRunning
        objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\KZM4FR\Documents\Ecosystem_Workbook_Full_Data_data.csv", ReadOnly:=True)
        objSheets = objBook.Worksheets
        objSheet = objSheets(1)

ExcelNotRunning:
        If (Not (Err.Number = 0)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Missing Workbook?")

            'We cannot automate Excel if we cannot find the data we created, 
            'so leave the subroutine.
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Get a range of data.
        range = objSheet.Range("A1", "E5")

        'Retrieve the data from the range.
        Dim saRet(,) As Object
        saRet = range.Value

        'Determine the dimensions of the array.
        Dim iRows As Long
        Dim iCols As Long
        iRows = saRet.GetUpperBound(0)
        iCols = saRet.GetUpperBound(1)

        'Build a string that contains the data of the array for testing.
        Dim valueString As String
        valueString = "Array Data" + vbCrLf

        Dim rowCounter As Long
        Dim colCounter As Long
        For rowCounter = 1 To iRows
            For colCounter = 1 To iCols

                'Write the next value into the string.
                valueString = String.Concat(valueString,
                    saRet(rowCounter, colCounter).ToString() + ", ")

            Next colCounter

            'Write in a new line.
            valueString = String.Concat(valueString, vbCrLf)
        Next rowCounter

        'Report the value of the array.
        MessageBox.Show(valueString, "Array Values")
    End Sub
```

[Image of the build message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrNL0.png)

Comment: Stop debugging (ie: close the form) before trying to build/rebuild the project.

Comment: Also, it's recommended to enable [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

Comment: @user9938 Excel automation may require late binding which conflicts with `Option Strict On`.  (Though as much as possible, this should be pulled out into a separate file with `Option Strict Off` with it `On` for everything else.)

Comment: Reading the error message, this problem has nothing to do with excel, or the code above.  The problem is the application is already running so you are unable to overwrite it with the new build.  Check the task manager

Comment: @Hursey I believed so as well but it's indicating that the program itself (winformsapp2) is blocking itself.

Correction: You were correct, but the item was hidden from me and recurred over restart.